# How to add a tooltip in xslt

Tags: html

I want to add a tooltip to an image as follows:

```
 <td align="center" >
    <xsl:value-of select="CatalogProduct"></xsl:value-of>           
    <xsl:if test="ProductCode = '002'">
    &#160;<img height="16" align="middle" src="/images/message_info.png" toolTip="Integrated Product"/>
    </xsl:if>
  </td>
```

toolTip="Value" doesnt work. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

title= "Value" also seems to work!